# Infinite line of charge in quantum mechanics

Tags: quantum-mechanics, electromagnetism

Suppose I have a finite line of charge with charge density $\lambda$ and lenght $L$. Then the electric potential $\phi$ from a distance $r$ from the center of the line is
$$\phi(r)=\frac{\lambda}{2\pi\epsilon_0}\int_0^L \frac{1}{\sqrt{r^2+x^2}}\mathrm{d}x=\frac{\lambda}{2\pi\epsilon_0}\ln\left(\sqrt{L^2+r^2}+L\right)-\frac{\lambda}{2\pi\epsilon_0}\ln r.$$
Because $E=-\nabla\phi$, we can add any constant to our potential without changing the field. So,
$$\phi(r)=\frac{\lambda}{2\pi\epsilon_0}\ln\left(\sqrt{L^2+r^2}+L\right)-\frac{\lambda}{2\pi\epsilon_0}\ln L - \frac{\lambda}{2\pi\epsilon_0}\ln r=\frac{\lambda}{2\pi\epsilon_0}\ln\left(\sqrt{1+r^2/L^2}+1\right)-\frac{\lambda}{2\pi\epsilon_0}\ln r.$$
Then, as $L\to\infty$,
$$\phi(r)\to-\frac{\lambda}{2\pi\epsilon_0}\ln r.$$
However, the potential doesn't appear through a derivative in Schrödinger's equation. Is this potential right in quantum mechanics? If not, then how do I derive it?

Comment: The Schroedinger equation is a non-relativistic field equation for a single massive particle (or a fixed number of them), but it can't describe an electromagnetic field, which is an inherently relativistic phenomenon. Nothing stops you from using the result of this calculation as a Schroedinger potential, of course. Whether that is "right" for your purposes, depends on your purposes. If you want to describe the motion of a non-relativistic charge around a wire, it's correct.